# Exibir detalhes digitados

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer com que depois de selecionar os dados apareça os detalhes do que eu digitei

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="pt-br">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Busca de Imovel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/formularios1.css" />
</head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Retira os espaços em branco//
            function trim(str) {return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");}

            function Buscar() {

                strNegocio = trim(document.frmDados.cbNegocio.value);
                strEstado = trim(document.frmDados.cbEstado.value);
                strCidade=trim(document.frmDados.cbCidade.value);
                strBairro=trim(document.frmDados.cbBairro.value);
                strTipo=trim(document.frmDados.cbTipo.value);
                strQuartos=trim(document.frmDados.cbQuartos.value);
                strCodigo=trim(document.frmDados.cbCodigo.value);

                if(strNegocio.length>0){
                    if(strEstado.length>0){
                        if(strCidade.length>0){
                            if(strBairro.length>0){
                                if(strTipo.length>0){
                                    if(strQuartos.length>0){
                                        if(strCodigo.length>0){
                                            document.frmDados.action="detalhes.php";
                                            document.frmDados.submit(); 


                                        }
                                        else{
                                            alert("Por favor informe o codigo")
                                            document.frmDados.cbCodigo.focus();
                                        }

                                    }
                                    else{
                                        alert("Por favor informe o numero de quartos")
                                        document.frmDados.cbQuartos.focus();
                                    }
                                }
                                else{
                                    alert("Por favor informe o tipo")
                                    document.frmDados.cbTipo.focus();
                                }

                            }
                            else{
                                alert("Por favor informe o bairro")
                                document.frmDados.cbBairro.focus();
                            }

                        }
                        else{
                            alert("Por favor informe a cidade")
                            document.frmDados.cbCidade.focus();
                        }

                    }
                    else{
                        alert("Por favor informe o estado")
                        document.frmDados.cbEstado.focus();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    alert("Por favor informe o negocio")
                    document.frmDados.cbNegocio.focus();
                }
        } 

            function Voltar() {
                document.frmDados.action="index.html";
                        document.frmDados.submit(); 
            }
    </script>
<body>
        <h1 align="center">Buscar imovel</h1>
        <form name="frmDados" id="frmDados" method="post">
        <table border="1" width="50%" id="tf" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td width="20%" height="37" bgcolor="" align="center">Negocio:</td>
                <td><select name="cbNegocio" id="cbNegocio">
                    <option value="">Selecione o Negocio..</option>
                    <?php
                        ini_set("display_errors","OFF");
                        $connect= mysql_pconnect ("localhost","root","");
                        mysql_select_db ("imovel");
                        $retFunc = mysql_query ("select imovel_id, negocio from imovel order by negocio asc");
                        while($linha = mysql_fetch_row($retFunc)){
                            print "<option value='" . $linha[0] . "'>" . $linha[1] . "</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%" height="37" bgcolor="" align="center">Estado:</td>
                <td><select name="cbEstado" id="cbEstado">
                    <option value="">Selecione o Estado..</option>
                    <?php
                        ini_set("display_errors","OFF");
                        $connect= mysql_pconnect ("localhost","root","");
                        mysql_select_db ("imovel");
                        $retFunc = mysql_query ("select imovel_id, estado from imovel order by estado asc");
                        while($linha = mysql_fetch_row($retFunc)){
                            print "<option value='" . $linha[0] . "'>" . $linha[1] . "</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%" height="37" bgcolor="" align="center">Cidade:</td>
                <td><select name="cbCidade" id="cbCidade">
                    <option value="">Selecione a Cidade..</option>
                    <?php
                        ini_set("display_errors","OFF");
                        $connect= mysql_pconnect ("localhost","root","");
                        mysql_select_db ("imovel");
                        $retFunc = mysql_query ("select imovel_id, cidade from imovel order by cidade asc");
                        while($linha = mysql_fetch_row($retFunc)){
                            print "<option value='" . $linha[0] . "'>" . $linha[1] . "</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%" height="37" bgcolor="" align="center">Bairro:</td>
                <td><select name="cbBairro" id="cbBairro">
                    <option value="">Selecione o Bairro..</option>
                    <?php
                        ini_set("display_errors","OFF");
                        $connect= mysql_pconnect ("localhost","root","");
                        mysql_select_db ("imovel");
                        $retFunc = mysql_query ("select imovel_id, bairro from imovel order by bairro asc");
                        while($linha = mysql_fetch_row($retFunc)){
                            print "<option value='" . $linha[0] . "'>" . $linha[1] . "</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%" height="37" bgcolor="" align="center">Tipo:</td>
                <td><select name="cbTipo" id="cbTipo">
                    <option value="">Selecione o Tipo..</option>
                    <?php
                        ini_set("display_errors","OFF");
                        $connect= mysql_pconnect ("localhost","root","");
                        mysql_select_db ("imovel");
                        $retFunc = mysql_query ("select imovel_id, tipo from imovel order by tipo asc");
                        while($linha = mysql_fetch_row($retFunc)){
                            print "<option value='" . $linha[0] . "'>" . $linha[1] . "</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%" height="37" bgcolor="" align="center">Quartos:</td>
                <td><select name="cbQuartos" id="cbQuartos">
                    <option value="">Selecione o Numero de Quartos..</option>
                    <?php
                        ini_set("display_errors","OFF");
                        $connect= mysql_pconnect ("localhost","root","");
                        mysql_select_db ("imovel");
                        $retFunc = mysql_query ("select imovel_id, quartos from imovel order by quartos asc");
                        while($linha = mysql_fetch_row($retFunc)){
                            print "<option value='" . $linha[0] . "'>" . $linha[1] . "</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%" height="37" bgcolor="" align="center">Codigo:</td>
                <td><select name="cbCodigo" id="cbCodigo">
                    <option value="">Selecione o Codigo do Imovel..</option>
                    <?php
                        ini_set("display_errors","OFF");
                        $connect= mysql_pconnect ("localhost","root","");
                        mysql_select_db ("imovel");
                        $retFunc = mysql_query ("select imovel_id, codigo from imovel order by codigo asc");
                        while($linha = mysql_fetch_row($retFunc)){
                            print "<option value='" . $linha[0] . "'>" . $linha[1] . "</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
                <td align="right" colspan="2">
                <input type="button" name="btnVoltar" id="btnVoltar" value="Voltar" onclick="Voltar()">
                <input type="button" name="btnCriar" id="btnCriar" align="right" value="Buscar" onclick="Buscar()"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </form>     
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Ficou muito vaga sua pergunta, poderia ser mais especifico?